# C++ - Changing ASM instruction of another file

Tags: c++, assembly, binary

I have been able to modify an executable to do exactly what I wanted to, using Ollydbg

```
006D0CFA  |. 84DB           TEST BL,BL
```

became

```
006D0CFA  |. 84DB           NOP
```

and it works perfectly.

Now, I want to do it with C++. I think I could use WriteProcessMemory, but that isn't what I am trying to do.

What I want to do is to make a C++ program (using Qt, I do'nt know if this information can help) to "patch" the binary. I want the binary file to be modified with the new instruction.

I tried to do that :

```cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QFile>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QtDebug>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QString textCracked = getFileText(FILE_CRACKED);
    QString textOriginal = getFileText(FILE_ORIGINAL);
    runDiff(textOriginal, textCracked);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

QString MainWindow::getFileText(QString filename)
{
    QFile file(filename + ".exe");
    QFile file2(filename + ".txt");
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
        return "";
    if (!file2.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text))
        return "";
    QTextStream in(&file);
    QTextStream in2(&file2);
    QString line = "";
    while (!in.atEnd()) {
        line += in.readAll();
        in2 << line;
    }
    file.close();
    file2.close();
    return line;
}

void MainWindow::runDiff(QString original, QString cracked)
{
    qDebug() << "Size : " << original.size();
    for(int i = 0 ; i < original.size() ; i++)
    {
        if(original[i] != cracked[i])
            qDebug() << i << ", Original : " << original[i] << " | Cracked : " << cracked[i];
    }
}
```

And i have this output :

```
Size :  3324384
2941742 , Original :  '\u201e'  | Cracked :  '\u0090'
2941743 , Original :  '\u00db'  | Cracked :  '\u0090'
```

Problems with my method :

- I have to make a binary to patch the second one, making it less usefull than expected.
- I can't use asm address
- My size is 3 324 384. I was expecting to have 2 957 310 (006D2FFE (last instruction in Ollydbg) - 401000 (first instruction in Ollydbg)). Where does this difference come from ?

Thank you in advance. I probably forgot something, don't hesitate to ask for more details.

Comment: 1) well yes, that's exactly what you set out to do 2) you need a file offset 3) don't use QTextStream

Comment: If you want to permanently modify another executable, you only need to do that once.  You can do it by hand with a hex editor; some even have x86 disassembly as a feature to help you check you're in the right place.

Comment: @Jester > 1)2) Problem is : i = 2 941 742 = 002C E32E‬. Add 40 1000 = 006C F32E
Official address = 006D 0CFA
Difference = 19CA (6602 decimal value)
But with another asm instruction, at another address, I get a difference of 144.                                   PeterCordes > As I told it in the message above : I already did it with Ollydbg, and it works. But I want to go further and to do make a soft where I can click on ome checkboxes and enable/disable some features. I don't want to build x^2 executables files. By the way : will instruction address change if the executable is updated ?

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  Your modifications to the executable won't change instruction addresses as long as you're merely overwriting bytes, not *inserting* bytes (which you could only do by making a copy of the file; there isn't a system call to insert a byte and move later bytes down.  Well technically there is, Linux `fallocate` can do that on some filesystems if supported, but you don't want that.)

Comment: Or if you meant would recompiling the executable from source change it?  Yes, certainly.  Any source change or new compiler version might or might not result in smaller or larger code in some function, changing the address of everything later.  If you want to make editable binaries, hand-write the relevant functions in asm and put labels on the editable positions, and make sure those symbols end up in the symbol table so your modifier program can use symbols to find the right place, instead of hard-coded file offsets.  (Then you'd need a metadata parsing library like libbfd maybe.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments, Nox clarified he wants to edit a file not a process.  Here is a simple project that illustrates how to patch a file:

```C++
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile("test.txt", FILE_ALL_ACCESS, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_DELETE, 0, CREATE_ALWAYS, 0, 0);
    CloseHandle(hFile);

    std::fstream fs("test.txt", std::ios::in | std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);

    fs.write("\x52\x61\x6B\x65\x53\x75\x63\x6B\x73", 10);
    std::streampos size = fs.tellg();

    char* buffer = new char[size];

    fs.seekg(0, std::ios::beg); //change offset here
    fs.read(buffer, size);

    std::cout << "file says: " << buffer << std::endl;

    fs.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    fs.write("\x52\x61\x6B\x65\x52\x6F\x63\x6B\x73", 10);

    std::cout << "file patched!\n";

    fs.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    fs.read(buffer, size);

    std::cout << "file says: " << buffer << std::endl;

    fs.close();
    delete[] buffer;

    return 0;
}
```

**Explanation:**

- Create a file
- Open the file stream with input, output and binary mode
- Write some bytes to it, these bytes represent the ASCII "RakeSucks"
- tellg() gives the current position of the stream, which is also the size
- To show you how you read from the file
- We use seekg() to go to the beginning
- If you wanted to go to a specific file offset for patching, replace 0 with your offset.
- We create a buffer and use read() to read the text we just wrote, then we output it to the console
- We then use seekg() to go back to the beginning of the file
- We use write() to overwrite our original bytes with new ones.
- Again, we read the bytes and it outputs "RakeRocks"

Answer (score 0):

Pages of memory that contain assembly instructions will have execute permissions but not write permissions.  In order to change them you must use [VirtualProtectEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualprotectex) before attempting to write.

To do so we can use a little wrapper to patch bytes:

```C++
void PatchEx(HANDLE hProcess, char* dst, char* src, int size)
{
    DWORD oldprotect;
    VirtualProtectEx(hProcess, dst, size, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &oldprotect);
    WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, dst, src, size, NULL);
    VirtualProtectEx(hProcess, dst, size, oldprotect, &oldprotect);
}
```

If you want to apply a NOP you can use this function:

```
void NopEx(char* dst, unsigned int size, HANDLE hProcess)
{
    char* nopArray = new char[size];
    memset(nopArray, 0x90, size);

    DWORD oldprotect;
    VirtualProtectEx(hProcess, dst, size, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &oldprotect);
    WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, dst, nopArray, size, NULL);
    VirtualProtectEx(hProcess, dst, size, oldprotect, &oldprotect);
    delete[] nopArray;
}
```

Comment: If efficiency of the patched code matters, you could have a table of long-nop sequences to choose from based on length.  e.g. `0x90`,  `66 90`, and longer ones using the `0f 1f mod/rm` long nop, like `0F 1F 00H`.  https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/NOP

Comment: Well, I didn't touch this project since, but I am not sure this can help my case. I want the .exe to be modified without having to launch anything else. As far as I know, VirtualProtectEx and WriteProcessMemory modify a process, not a file. Am I wrong ?

Comment: @Nox correct WriteProcessMemory acts on a process, not a file.  I will post another answer for patching a file.